# How to redirect the site url

Tags: magento-1.7, url, redirect

[Main site url](http://naijashop.com.ng)

I have removed the index.hmtl file from root but still site is redirecting to index.html and i couldn't find any mode rewrite in the htaccess file. But site is still redirecting to index.html.

How to remove the redirection or re - redirect into index.php

Suggest me please.

Comment: RewriteRule ^/index.html$ http://yoursite.com/index.php/[R=301,L]

Comment: no luck @Thomas

Comment: Goto System->configuration-> on left side select web->Search Engines Optimization set yes

Comment: It is already set to yes.

Answer (score 1):

goto your htaccess file of magento root dir

Find ***DirectoryIndex*** and  set ***index.php*** as default index file

Put it code as

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

If it  doest not work then discuss with `your hosting provide`r They may be define default index in apache  **config. file**.

Also check  the system  in private browser

Comment: DirectoryIndex index.php is already in the .htaccess file and it is correct

Comment: @BishalNeupane perhaps your apache config does not allow overwrites thats why your htaccess is not working

Comment: Can i configure the apache config file with godady hosting